# Pre-optimized-min file named with GUID Sitecore SXA 10.2

Tags: sxa, unicorn, sxa-cli

We use Unicorn in our project, and we are saving the **pre-optimized-min.yml** files in source control. Here is the exclude predicate we have for this file:

```
<exclude childrenOfPath="/sitecore/media library/Themes/<Name>/<Name>/styles">
     <except name="pre-optimized-min" />
</exclude>
```

We use a standard SXA CLI Setup.

[image]

The problem is that after minification, SOMETIMES, the yml file is saved with a GUID at the end of the name:

[image]

This is causing issues in our CI/CD pipeline as the file is not recognized and our styles are not picked up correctly.

Any ideas on this could be happening?

Answer (score 2):

`pre-optimized-min` items are generated automatically. Each time with new id.

When you save `pre-optimized-min.yml` in your source control, next time someone checks out from source control and their Sitecore generates new `pre-optimized-min`, it wants to serialize that new item, but it checks that there is already a file like that on the drive, so it adds guid to the file name.

Normally, when SXA deletes old 'pre-optimized-min` item, it deletes serialized item as well. But because you keep the old one in source control, there are situations that old one is still there from source control, a new one is created with guid in filename.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a consequence of multiple items with the same name added into the media library. Unicorn detects this and writes a new file (presumably with a new GUID) to disk but then has to append the GUID to the filename to avoid conflicts.